# "I use to", or "I used to"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, time

Which is the correct sentence, if there is a correct one?

> I use to be a hitman.

> I used to be a hitman.

I've read the second sentence recently in a book, but I was sure it should be *I use to be a hitman*.

Comment: Related: [“supposed to” or “suppose to”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/supposed-to-or-suppose-to/8130#8130)

Comment: The correct way of saying this sentence is **/ay'ustəbiyə'hɪtnæn/**. The important part is that "used to" must be pronounced /yustə/, with an /st/, **not** a /zd/. This is true for the past terminative idiom in this example, and also for the different idiom _be used to_, meaning 'be accustomed to', as in the second clause in _I used to have trouble sleeping, but now I'm used to the train whistles in the night_. The construction that gets pronounced with /zd/ goes like this: _A shovel is used to dig with_. That's not an idiom, and not a constituent, either.

Answer (score 32):

As reported by the NOAD in a note about the usage of *used*:

> There is sometimes confusion over whether to use the form *used to* or *use to*, which has arisen largely because the pronunciation is the same in both cases. Except in negatives and questions, the correct form is *used to*: *we used to go to the movies all the time* (not *we use to go to the movies*). However, in negatives and questions using the auxiliary verb *do*, the correct form is *use to*, because the form of the verb required is the infinitive: *I didn't use to like mushrooms* (not *I didn't used to like mushrooms*).

About the negative of *used to*, the NOAD reports the following note:

> Traditionally, *used to* behaves as a modal verb, so that questions and negatives are formed without the auxiliary verb do, as in *it used not to be like that* and *used she to come here?* In modern English, this question form is now regarded as very formal or awkwardly old-fashioned, and the use with *do* is broadly accepted as standard, as in *did she use to come here?* Negative constructions with *do*, on the other hand (as in *it didn't use to be like that*), although common, are informal and are not generally accepted.

See also the *Usage* section for [*use*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/use) in the *Oxford Living Dictionaries*.

Comment: maybe it's the Northeast, but I would expect that *It used not to be like that.* would be much less common than *It didn't use to be like that.* The NOAD are showing their British bias. See [this American](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=didn+%27+t+use+to%2Cdidn+%27+t+used+to%2Cused+not+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) and [this British](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=didn+%27+t+use+to%2Cdidn+%27+t+used+to%2Cused+not+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) Ngram

Comment: @Peter Shor The NOAD is compiled by American editors.

Comment: the other, maybe more likely, possibility is that this entry in the NOAD is out of date. I am quite sure that *"It didn't use to be like that"* is generally accepted in American English nowadays, but it might not have been 15 years ago when the NOAD was first being compiled. The Ngram shows that in American English *used not to* occurred less than half as frequently as *didn't use(d) to* in 2008, and its use has been steadily declining.

Comment: It seems odd to me that "used she to come here?" is marked as formal (old-fashioned and awkward I agree with). The "used to" construction registers with me as being fundamentally informal. In a formal context I'd expect "did she formerly come here?" or some other wordier phrase. (AmE speaker)

Answer (score 14):

The second form is the correct one, confusion can come that when spoken the sound of the *d* and *t* comes nearly together.

Comment: Some regional dialects/accents pronounce "used" with a "z" in this case, as is normally done in other uses of the conjugation ("used car"), allowing for differentiation in speech. However, when speaking quickly, or in other dialects, this becomes difficult or impossible.

Comment: *Used to* in this sense is usually pronounced with a /t/, even though it's spelled with a "d".

Answer (score 12):

The second is correct.

Your doubts may come from another rule, that following the auxiliary *did* or *didn't*, the form *use to* should be used.  For example, if you want to ask someone if they were a hitman, you would say

> Didn't you **use to** be a hitman?

And the answer might be

> No I didn't **use to** be a hitman.

or, as in your example

> Yes, I **used to** be a hitman.

Comment: Not wanting to pick a nit here, but for the second answer, what does "didn't use to be" imply?

Comment: No problem it's not a nit pick!  This implies that the asker thinks the person was a hitman.  "Did you use to be.." is more neutral "You didn't use to be.... did you?" would  imply the opposite.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I was trying to say was that , while grammatically and semantically correct, the answer would probably be an indignant " No, I was never a hitman." Somehow, your version sounds as if the denial is not strong enough.

Comment: No, I'd stay cool, or give you a bunch of fives.  Indignation would only look weak.   You're not going to ask your aunty if she was a hitman are you?

Comment: For me, "I didn't use to be a hitman" implies "I still am a hitman".

Comment: Yup, exactly what I meant, this seems to be a guarded response to me.

Comment: @Daniel That makes no sense at all, unless you assume the person is flatly lying.

Comment: @z7sg I don't understand why you say that. "I didn't *use* to be a hitman, I *am* a hitman" makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Daniel Check again, that's not what I wrote.  If you are *still* a hitman and you leave out "I *am* a hitman" from that response you are misleading the asker.  OK not 'flatly lying' but... this is ridiculous!

Comment: So to conjugate the past tense of "use" it's "I used","You use", "He use","They use" - is that correct?

Comment: @Chris No, it's "You used to", "He used to", "They used to".  It is only the form with *did* that is "They did use to (be hitmen or whatever)"

Comment: Can we use 'use to' in simple present tense?

Comment: @pinkpanther What would you want that to mean?

Answer (score 2):

The second one is correct, and this is why:

"used to" means that the person originally had whatever characteristic was being described, but no longer has it. i.e. the person was originally a hitman, but no longer is.

The reason it is in the past tense, is because it is describing something in the past, something that no longer exists, but did in times past.

Answer (score 2):

Use is **present tense**

Used is **past tense**

If you are talking about having been a hit man in the **past**, then obviously the **past tense** - **used** - should be used.

Answer (score -1):

Tense should be the deciding factor. *Used* indicates past tense, in this case indicating that the gentleman was, at some point, a hitman.