# 'I couldn't use to' instead of 'I didn't use to be able to/I used not to'

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs

I heard this over the weekend -

*I've been going to evening classes and now, at last, I can touch type.  I **couldn't use** to do that.*

I would normally say

'*I didn't use to be able to do that*', or

'*I used not to be able to do that*'.

Both of my 'correct' answers seem very wordy.  Can it be said better?

Comment: It doesn't seem especially wordy to me (no more so than "I may be able to do that" compared to "I may can do that").

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I use to", or "I used to"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30035/i-use-to-or-i-used-to)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Not a duplicate!

Comment: Depends how you look at it. Two out of three of your examples "incorrectly" use ***use*** instead of ***used***, so that's a legitimate issue to be addressed on ELU. Asking for a completely *different* way to phrase things is open-ended writing advice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - my question sought an idiomatic (rather than an idiosyncratic) way of saying what I heard at the weekend - '*I couldn't use to do that*'.  When I heard this I instantly knew what was meant but was unable to come up with a short 'correct' version.  The answer posted below has answered my question (and was not part of the answer to the 'possible duplicate' question you linked (which was about use/used)).

Comment: Apart from the fact that no-one apart from the most prescriptive grammarians could argue which is "correct" out of *couldn't **use** to* and *couldn't **used** to* (a distinction which *can't* be made in speech), I think the only reason you class either of those as "idiosyncratic" is because of the semantic clash when conjoining negated *ability* (was able to) and *habit* (was accustomed to). That's why that particular form is relatively uncommon. But when we introduce do-support, ***used*** shifts to meaning just *did [but **no longer do**]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think we may be at cross-purposes.  I was very happy and accepting of the phrase I heard.  It was a new usage to me and I found myself struggling to come up with the casual way in which I would say the say thing.  michael_timofeev found the answer for me!

Comment: Well, I don't know why you think *I couldn't before* is more "informal" than *I previously couldn't* - the former is about 40 times more common in Google Books, and the only reason I can think of for suggesting the latter  is more formal is that it's *unusual* phrasing (but I think it's just "clunky"). Whatever - I suppose we *are* at cross-purposes, since I think the "writing advice" aspect is Off Topic, and that the only aspect of the Q that *is* On Topic is the *use/used* distinction that should be covered by that earlier question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'couldn't use to' does not feature in the 'possible duplicate' link you have suggested.  Where do you find your evidence to assert that 'couldn't use to' is "incorrect"?

Comment: Ngrams usage suggests otherwise - https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=couldn't+use+to%2C+couldn't+used+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccould%20not%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say: "I previously couldn't do that."

Comment: Yes, I guess.  Or, more informally, 'I couldn't do that *before*'.

Comment: @Dan Yes.  I don;t think there is much difference between yours and mine in terms of formality.  Actually, I think yours is much cleaner.

Comment: @Dan Sure thing, Dan!