# Meaning based on emphasis

Tags: meaning, subjects, emphasis, syllables

Is there a term used to explain how some words change meaning based on the accent? For example, "convict" can be both a noun and a verb depending on which syllable is emphasized. The same is true for "reject", "pervert", "subject", "address" and probably others.

Is there a technical term for this?

Comment: It all depends what you mean by "word". In some ways, these can all be seen as homonymic pairs of words, each pair consisting of a verb and a noun, with closely-connected meanings, but different pronunciations. It's a bit like the verb *have/had*, which has the variant pronunciation *haff/hat* [only when in the 'obligation' sense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/pronunciation-of-have-in-i-dont-have-to-do-something/46014#46014)

Comment: That's a good point about haff/hat. Though it isn't accent, as much as it is phonology. Still, there might be a connection.

Comment: I don't know why you mention *accent*. The connection is that *semantic* variations are expressed through phonological variations in both cases. In this context, I consider the noun/verb differences to be differences in *meaning*, rather than simply matters of grammar or "parts of speech".

Comment: You are talking about "stress", which is quite separate from "emphasis".

Answer (score -5, accepted):

*Tone* is the term. Other languages are much more tonal than English, and are [classified as such.](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-tonal-language.htm)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_%28linguistics%29) says:

> Tone is the use of pitch in language to distinguish lexical or
>   grammatical meaning—that is, to distinguish or inflect words. All
>   verbal languages use pitch to express emotional and other
>   paralinguistic information, and to convey emphasis, contrast, and
>   other such features in what is called *intonation*, but not all
>   languages use tones to distinguish words or their inflections,
>   analogously to consonants and vowels. Such tonal phonemes are
>   sometimes called **tonemes**.

Comment: Isn't there something more specific? "Tone" could refer to other things as well.

Comment: I expanded my answer. Is "intonation" more of what you were looking for?

Comment: Intonation makes more sense! Thank you for adding the word "toneme"! I'll have to remember that one for the future. I also found the term "suprafixation" which I think might be another good one.

Comment: You're welcome. 

I wish downvoters had both the courtesy and the courage to state why they downvoted.

Comment: I agree. I kind of wondered about that.

Comment: "Tone" does not describe what's going on here, neither does "intonation". This is simply a matter of *stress*, which is related to but distinct from tone and intonation.

Comment: English is more tonal than most people realize.

Comment: I still think all those down-votes are a bit harsh. One could say stress is partially expressed by tone, and stress is indeed relevant.

Comment: In many Asian languages (my background), what is accomplished by lexical stress in English is entirely performed by tone. (Then again, a lot of "me too" often goes on with voting.)

Answer (score 6):

Such words are called **heteronyms**. The famous Venn diagram from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_%28linguistics%29):

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you for adding this chart! I'm going to save this for help in the future.