# "He has to do it. Hasn't he (to)?"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, question-tags

> He has to do it. Hasn't he (to)?

Is the '*to*' correct/ incorrect/ unnecessary?

Is that a case of an infinitive in interrogative tail (question tag)?

Comment: You've got to be kidding, don't you to?

Comment: *dont you* would be more than enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Have to* is an idiom, a paraphrase of the [modal auxiliary verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/modals.html) *must*; it's always pronounced **/'hæftə/** (**/'hæstə/** in 3SgPres -- **always** /f/ instead of /v/ and /s/ instead of /z/), and it can't be split up.

Modal paraphrase idioms like *hafta, wanna, gotta*, etc. are written with *to* in formal spelling, but that's just a marker for the infinitive that has to follow *hasta*, and it also has to be all in one unit. You can't say, for instance,

- **Last night I had three times to get up and go to the bathroom.*

instead of

- *Last night I had to get up and go to the bathroom three times.*

because it splits up *had* and *to*. You can't even contract a negative with it

- **She hasn't to go to work today; it's a holiday.*

is ungrammatical, while

- *She doesn't have to go to work today; it's a holiday.*

with [*Do*-Support](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78549/can-be-be-used-with-the-modal-verb-do/78591#78591), **is** grammatical.

That's why it doesn't form a normal tag question; the tag requires a contracted negative, and that's ungrammatical. Instead, as Rory, Kris, and Noah all suggest, using *do/does/did* of *Do*-Support is the correct solution.

Comment: +1 interesting! I didn't know that these were unitary lexemes, but it makes so much sense now that I do.

Comment: [Here's](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/hafta.html) the link to your summary of */haeft@/* vs */haevtu/* - which is how I knew who you were a few months before you signed up to ELU, because PLL included the link in his answer to [my earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/) about that difference.

Comment: Thanks again, FF. I've explained it so many times in so many places that I forget where they are.

Comment: It's the fact that you don't even bother to deal with the word "have" in isolation that fascinates me. Obviously you're right in that it's just a component of "hafta", which in speech we all treat as a "single unit". Presumably because I normally either *write* words or *speak* them (but not both at the same time), I don't automatically recognise that "collapsed into a single unit" at the conscious level. But my Wernicke's area (or Broca's area, or whatever) always gets excited when you tell me something *it* "knows", that "I" don't!

Comment: Literacy is simply technology for transcribing speech. It misses a lot, but if you're a fluent reader, you're using your speech centres when you read. That's why poetry works, even in writing; and why poetry meant to be spoken (e.g, song lyrics) is so different from poetry meant to be read.

Comment: Really, the fact that we write _"have to"_ instead of _"hafta"_ -- like the fact that English spelling sucks so much -- is an artifact of the date when printing was introduced to the British Isles. If only Caxtond weitd a censhry or tu, speling maytv bin much simplr.

Comment: "She hasn't to go to work today" sounds a little old-fashioned and formal, but I would say it is still grammatical.

Comment: Must agree with Tony here. “She hasn’t to go to work today; it’s a holiday” and “Last night I had three times to get up and go to the bathroom” are both incorrect (it’s not a holiday, and I slept like a log) and quite a bit precious, if not old-fashioned; but in BrE, they’re both perfectly grammatical as well. Even in AmE, I’d only label them archaising, not ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance you would not need that final 'to' - it would be far too cumbersome.

Or even better:

> He has to do it, doesn't he?

as that final part translates as... doesn't he have to?

Comment: Yes, "*, doesn't he?*" is the usual and more elegant way, though it isn't possible to explain grammatically as it is.

Comment: Yes. "Hasn't he?" would more often appear as a reply-of-surprise to the news that someone hasn't done something they were supposed to. "He hasn't brought in the horses." "Hasn't he? That little layabout!"

Comment: This is a use of the non-idiomatic auxiliary verbs _have_ and _has_   (pronounced /hæv/ and /hæz/) of the Perfect construction, and that's the regular situation. The idiom is different.

Answer (score 1):

In OP's specific context, "**has**" would normally be pronounced "**hass**", as per [this earlier question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/pronunciation-of-have-in-i-dont-have-to-do-something)

To my ear, *"He **hass** to do it"* followed by *", hasn't he?"* is "disjunctive", because the first instance of the word is both vocally stressed *and* pronounced differently to the shortened second occurrence.

In light of the above, I might be tempted to recast OP's version to *"He has to do it, **has he not**?"*. But in reality, I'd probably say *"He has to do it, **doesn't he**?"* - or more likely, I just wouldn't append that slightly awkward [question tag](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/questionstags/menu.php) anyway. But in no circumstances would I (or any other native speaker, I suspect) echo the word *"to"* in the tag.

Comment: You mean that `/hæz/` devoices to `/hæs/`.  Saying *has* and *hass* is meaningless.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't see how my failing to use the technical term "devoice" makes any of my text "meaningless". Even I (just about) know the term - but obviously John Lawler would be intimately familiar with it, and he's certainly not averse to using much rarer terminology. But even he didn't feel it necessary to use the word in his answer above.

Comment: You miss the point: yoor yoozing cylli speekNspelle, instead of IPA, as John did.   SpeekNSpelle iz
 yooceliss.

Comment: @tchrist: Of course it's not "useless" - it just irritates *you*, is all. In this specific case, *everyone* will understand what difference in pronunciation I'm referring to when I write *has | hass*, but there will certainly be *some* people who wouldn't get it (or at least, not so easily) if I'd written */hæz/ | /hæs/*