# Question tag for a sentence of future tense

Tags: grammaticality, question-tags

For a sentence of future tense, one containing a form of the verb "be", should the question tag include that form of "be"?

Example:

Which sentence is correct?

1. I would be in the city, wouldn't I be?
2. I would be in the city, wouldn't I?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/81076/14666

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reuse the 'be' - it is implied, so the second sentence is correct.

Similarly, 'I could sit on that chair, couldn't I?'

Comment: +1, exactly. You wouldn't say, "I could sit on the chair, couldn't I sit?"

Answer (score -1):

The verb "to be" can be used as the main verb tense or as the auxiliary verb.

The verb to be is used as the main verb tense to state that something or someone exists.

Rules for using the verb tense "to be":

The verb tense "to be" changes form according to the subject when used as both the auxiliary verb and the main verb.

The verb "to be" changes form according to the subject when used as both the auxiliary verb or as the main verb.

When the verb tense "to be" is used as a main verb tense it is used in the simple tense only.

When the verb tense "to be" is the only verb, when used as a main verb.

When the verb tense "to be" is used as the main verb tense.

Negative statements/sentence use the word "not" without "do - does - did". - - - Questions are formed by putting the verb "to be:" before the subject.
The verb "to be" is an irregular verb.
is that clear?

Comment: Hello Anissa. This seems like very basic information very badly presented. It doesn't answer the original question in any way.